# How to verify the page title

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber and capybara along with rails 2.3.9.

How do I verify the page title? I try to have a good page title for every GET request and would like to verify that in my cucumber tests.

Comment: i don't know about cucumber much -- can it get the page title too?  Otherwise you can use Nokogiri -- there is a Rails Cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it.

```
Then /^I should see page title as "(.*)"$/ do |title|
  assert_equal title, page.find(:css, 'title').text
end
```